# Efficient logging for a WCF RESTful API in production

Tags: c#, wcf, error-handling

I'm about to do the logging for a RESTful WCF API. What are the important parts that should be logged and how can I keep all the error handling in one place.

This is what I think I'll need for any error when it happens:

1. Implement `IErrorHandler` so no exceptions go uncaught, from here I could add exceptions to a database and do alerts
2. All the `HTTP request details`
3. The error that was thrown with details about objects related to error

I've implemented **1.** but I'm not sure how to implement **2.** and for **3.** I'd need to write code for each method/endpoint and do a catch then add additional details of the error then re-throw it. And once the exception reaches the error handler it would have all the information it needs, that way I'm doing all the alerts and processing of errors in one place the ErrorHandler.

```
public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler, IServiceBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(
        ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
        ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,
        Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        IErrorHandler errorHandler = new ErrorHandler();

        foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase channelDispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher = channelDispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;
            if (channelDispatcher != null)
            {
                channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(errorHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(error.ToString());
        // Returning true indicates you performed your behavior of handling error.
        return true;
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        // Shield the unknown exception
        FaultException faultException = new FaultException("Server error encountered. All details have been logged.");
        MessageFault messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();
        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, faultException.Action);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use ELMAH package for error logging into db.

Comment: 1, 2, and 3 are all different features. It looks like you are asking us to write the code for 2 and 3. Are you sure this is a question?

Comment: No just how I can get these details, eg tell me what class/feature of WCF would be used for this. I was looking at Application_BeginRequest() in global asax and thought there might be some way to get all the http details from here, then its a matter of getting it to the error handler. I don't want to make a mess of things here so better to ask SO